# Delete statement not working in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying delete multiple records from store procedure SQL-Server 2012. I have select and then delete statement, apparently my delete statement is not been called

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteFunctionsNavigation]

 @FunctionName nvarchar(250),
 @Function_identity INT OUTPUT
   AS
   BEGIN    
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT Navigation_Functions.Function_ID 
FROM Navigation_Functions 
WHERE Navigation_Functions.FunctionName = @FunctionName
SET @Function_identity=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

DELETE FROM Navigation_FunctionHierarchy
WHERE Navigation_FunctionHierarchy.Function_IDs = @Function_identity

   RETURN
END
```

Comment: Please provide data sample and parameter value to call the stored procedure.

Comment: is Function_IDs defined as identity(autoincremental) ? Your delete is being called, the value of @Function_identity is most likely null

Comment: are you trying to delete the last inserted row ? What exactly are you trying to delete ? SCOPE_IDENTITY() Will return maximum identity inserted into the table(including rollback and deleted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is incorrect in this context. Try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteFunctionsNavigation]

 @FunctionName nvarchar(250),
 @Function_identity INT OUTPUT
   AS
   BEGIN    
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @Function_identity = Navigation_Functions.Function_ID 
FROM Navigation_Functions 
WHERE Navigation_Functions.FunctionName = @FunctionName


DELETE FROM Navigation_FunctionHierarchy
WHERE Navigation_FunctionHierarchy.Function_IDs = @Function_identity

   RETURN
END
```